# Prepending content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What is the best way to repeat the content in this slideshow, so when you click `.left` and the carousal starts moving, you get a neverending loop? At the moment, if you click `.left`, the carousal starts moving and leaves behind empty space.

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/mZRQx/1/

```
var loop;
var moveRight = function(){
    $('.box').animate({left: '-=10'}, 100);
};

var moveLeft = function(){
    $('.box').animate({left: '+=10'}, 100);

};

$('.right').mousedown(function(){
    loop = setInterval(moveRight, 200);
}).mouseup(function(){
    clearInterval(loop);
});

$('.left').mousedown(function(){
    loop = setInterval(moveLeft, 200);
}).mouseup(function(){
    clearInterval(loop);
});
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: FYI, you have other problems with your logic because if you mouse down on a button, then drag off and mouse up somewhere else, you get stuck intervals.  You should always clear the previous interval before starting a new one and if you really want to do the up/down behavior, you should probably capture the mouse so you never miss the mouse up.

Comment: Why not use one of the many carousels that already do this? Like http://www.catchmyfame.com/catchmyfame-jquery-plugins/jquery-infinite-carousel-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demo for your 'left' movement (though I think you got directions confused):

```
var moveLeft = function(){
    $('.box').animate({left: '+=10'}, 100, function(){
        var $last = $('.box').last();
        if ($last.css('left') == '100px') {
            $last.prependTo('.container').before('\n\r');
            $('.box').css('left','0px');
        }
    });
};
```

It checks whether elements shifted by 100px and if so - moves the last element before first. Note I am also adding CrLf there to keep original formatting and distance between the DIVs (remove it if u don't need it).

**"Left" Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mZRQx/3/**